# Scala Play Read Form Input

Tags: playframework

I'd like to read the value of an 'input,' and then the controller will pass the input to the `getTask(task: String)` method.

How can I do that? Here's my code snippet.

```
@form(routes.Application.getTask("url")) {

        @inputText(taskForm("hash"))

        <input type="submit" value="Get">

    }
```

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. I don't understand what you mean by: _controller will pass the input to the `getTask...`_ .Binding data in controllers is described in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaForms

Comment: Basically I want to add an input that accepts an Integer (hash). Then, I want Task.scala's `getTask(hash: Int)` method to do a DB look-up for the corresponding URL, and then show the URL on the page. But I don't know how to achieve this using code similar to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the html `<input>` tag should be rendered in the browser, your dom should look something like this (say, for a form styled with twitter bootstrap that handles logging on with a username and password):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/support/login" method="post">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">User Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="username" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Forgot Password</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

you post the form either with jquery.ajax, or by clicking on a `<button type="submit" ...>`. this will send a request to the server which play framework will handle,, that code looks something like this for me in scala:

```
  private def loginForm() = Form(
    tuple("username" -> text, "password" -> text)
      .verifying("Invalid username or password", result => Auth.authenticate(result._1, result._2)))

  def doLogin = Action { implicit request =>
    loginForm().bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => authenticationFailed(request),
      form => gotoLoginSucceeded(UserId(form._1))
    )
  }
```

`formWithErrors` and `form` are the parsed form objects.

Comment: it's really this much code? look how simple the "newTask" method is: 
 `<h2>Add a new tinyUrl</h2>
 
 @form(routes.Application.newTask) {
  
   @inputText(taskForm("url"))
   
   <input type="submit" value="Create">
   
  }`

Comment: i just pasted some stuff that i know works, im sure you can simplify